# $destroy is not being called when element is removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have a directive that's added to forms, and I need to know when a form is removed from the DOM. I'm trying to detect it with the $destroy event, but when I call .remove() on an element the $destroy event is not triggered.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a correct way to tell when it's removed from the DOM?

Relevant code:

The HTML:

```
<form id="myform" form-watch>
```

In the controller:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
// DOES NOT trigger $destroy
form.remove();

// DOES trigger $destroy
//angular.element(form).scope().$destroy();
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('formWatch', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            alert('destroyed');
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrQ1byiEgkdMGLnd5xs6)

EDIT: Here's a much more accurate picture of what I'm working with: [new plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UvhZbflqKJY2YcCWnR6U)

Comment: need to realize that scope is controller scope in this instance since directive isn't using an isolated scope. Controller is still active so removing the element isn't going to destroy the controller scope. Also why not use `ng-if` instead of manipulating the DOM? There should never be any dom manipulation code in a controller. What exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: Noted. Essentially, the app has clickable components all over, and clicking one swaps out the read-only display with a value (in a form) for submitting changes. I'm using this form-watch directive to track a page-wide "editing" state. If something causes the form to be removed, I need to know that I'm no longer editing.

Comment: All the more reason to use scope model, or $state to control that dom element's existence. If you are doing this sort of dom manipulation yourself it is a big mistake

Comment: In my defense, it was someone else's mistake. Can you expand on what you mean by using scope model?

Comment: Simple example...form is in own controller, but could be directive also with isolated scope to do same, or nested view  http://plnkr.co/edit/V4jVMWBO4ifsiIn6kE0v?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure that what you are really concerned with is the actual destroy event itself, but rather a way in the app to know when the form exists or not.

This should be monitored through the controllers and services in the app.

The issue I think is that there is dom manipulation going on that shouldn't be there ... By using proper scope models and designing views to be solely driven by scope models angular should be doing almost all of the dom manipulation , if not all of it.

Following example acheives the alert you want by wrapping form in it's own controller and using `ng-if` and a scope variable to determine whether form exists or not:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showForm = true;
});

app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    alert('destroyed');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!-- form has it's own controller -->
  <form ng-if="showForm" ng-controller="FormCtrl"></form>

 <!-- button in MainCtrl scope -->
 <button ng-click="showForm = !showForm">Toggle form</button>
```

Whenever form is removed by `ng-if` the FormCtrl scope is destroyed and the `$destroy` event is triggered. However watching the scope variable that determines form existence is likely what you are really after

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/V4jVMWBO4ifsiIn6kE0v?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Above you mentioned a directive would work too, but it doesn't seem to for me. Here's a much more accurate picture of what I'm working with: http://plnkr.co/edit/UvhZbflqKJY2YcCWnR6U

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that there are LOTS of different "click-to-edit" directives in the app, which is why I'm trying to keep this as simple as possible by just dropping the form-watch directive on them.

Comment: Ok...same thing without DOM manipulation ... simple addition of `ng-if` on same `isEditing` variable  http://plnkr.co/edit/dlmBnpnBSNGLrrdmbDFU?p=preview  Code is actually simpler and does what you were hoping it to do...throw the alert

Comment: check out `x-editable` ... great click to edit with angular module also

Comment: Getting much closer, thank you. Do I have access to the element (the form) in the directive controller? or the form controller? With this solution, how do I handle monitoring the form's $dirty property?

Comment: Would need form tag for that and name and would be in form directive scope. Defintely look at x-editable... is far more robust than this is and takes care of the validation promises events etc

Answer (score 1):

The scope destruction is not connected to the DOM automatically - so if you want to remove a directive manually, IMO the correct way is to call $destroy() and then remove any related dom explicitly.

So I would move the element's removal to the $destroy callback and trigger it with the code you already have

```
angular.element(form).scope().$destroy();
```

and in your directive

```
scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    element.remove();
});
```

HTH